# Como concatenar resultados de um SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenação-de-string, inner, inner-join

Tenho duas Tabelas: `Produtos`, `Eventos` e ProdutosEventos(proveniente da relação muitos para muitos das tabelas Produtos e Eventos):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realizei o seguinte SQL para pegar os dados do evento e os produtos presentes neste evento, e obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
SELECT        p.nome, e.titulo, e.descricao, e.obs, e.cupom, e.inicio, e.fim
FROM            ((eventos e INNER JOIN
                         ProdutosEventos pe ON e.idevento = pe.idevento) INNER JOIN
                         produtos p ON pe.idproduto = p.idproduto)
WHERE        (e.fim >= NOW) AND (e.inicio <= NOW)
```

Resultado:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este resultado foi esperado, entretanto gostaria que os nomes dos produtos que estão presentes no evento ficassem em uma mesma coluna, ou seja, gostaria que em vez de 4 resultados, cada um com um produto, gostaria de 1 resultado com os 4 produtos dessa forma:

> nome: x-Tudo, X-Tudo², Porção de Calabresa, Porção de Fritas.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que deve ser feito para alcançar esse resultado?

Comment: Utilize a função de agregação GROUP_CONCAT juntamente com a cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: Utilizei, ficou assim: `SELECT        e.titulo, e.descricao, e.obs, e.cupom, e.inicio, e.fim, GROUP_CONCAT(p.nome) AS teste
FROM            ((eventos e INNER JOIN
                         ProdutosEventos pe ON e.idevento = pe.idevento) INNER JOIN
                         produtos p ON pe.idproduto = p.idproduto)
WHERE        (e.fim >= NOW) AND (e.inicio <= NOW)
GROUP BY e.idevento` Mas ele retorna um erro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkMpJ.png Sabe o que seria?

Comment: Qual o bd ? Mysql ?

Comment: Access, estou desenvolvendo em VB.NET

Comment: Se você está utilizando Access porquê marcou a tag MySQL? Que eu saiba o Microsoft Access não tem uma função de agregação similar ao GROUP_CONCAT do MySql.

Comment: eita, marquei este mysql sem querer, você não sabe se tem alguma maneira de concatenar no Acess?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access?rq=1  resolvendo na aplicação , Acess é muito limitado.